# How to calculate the inner distance of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to workout the distance between the inner values of two consecutive items in an array.

For examples:

```
>>> _array=[(5, 10), (15, 20), (25, 30), (35, 40)]
>>> np_array=[np.array(x) for x in _array]
>>> distance=[x - np_array[i - 1] for i, x in enumerate(np_array)][1:]
>>> distance
[array([10, 10]), array([10, 10]), array([10, 10])]
```

The example above calculates the distance between the items. What I'm really after is the distance between the inner attributes of any two consecutive items in the array i.e

```
(15-10),(25-20),(35-30)
```

Desired output: `[(5),(5),(5)]`

Any suggestions on how to go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, because using non-NumPy datastructures with NumPy defeats the whole point:

```
_array = numpy.asarray(_array)
```

Then, just slice and subtract:

```
distances = array[1:, 0] - array[:-1, 1]
```

`array[1:, 0]` gets the first coordinate of all points after the first, `array[:-1, 1]` gets the second coordinate of all points before the last, and the subtraction is applied elementwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([(5, 10), (15, 20), (25, 30), (35, 40)])

a[1:, 0] - a[:-1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply access the index `[0]` for the current tuple and `[1]` for the previous one:

```
distance = [x[0] - np_array[i - 1][1] for i, x in enumerate(np_array)][1:]
```

Comment: While this works, if the OP is using NumPy, doing things with loops and list comprehensions defeats almost every benefit of NumPy.

Comment: @user2357112, thank you very much for the insight. I really want to take advantage of the benefit from numpy speed.